# No redirect to human readable (rewritten) product URL?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

Magento 2.4.6

I just noticed that all products in my shop can be reached on the not rewritten url like https://www.myshop.com/catalog/product/view/id/174750/category/2/ and also under https://www.myshop.com/my-product.

I did not experience this with other Magento 2 shops. What could be the reason for that?

Thanks